# How to create a TextSwitcher in a custom ProgressBar widget

Tags: android, custom-controls, progress-bar

Is it possible to extend two widgets in android?  I'm new still but I'm trying to combine a textswitcher with a progress bar so that the text switcher is OVER the progress bar.   I've got the following top part of a custom progress bar widget that can do normal text, but I'd like to try and change static text into a textswitcher so that it can change the text displayed in a nice animated fashion:

```
public class TextProgressBar extends ProgressBar {  
private String text;  
private Paint textPaint;  

public TextProgressBar(Context context) {  

    super(context);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "frankleinmedium.ttf");
    text = "Paid Off";  
   // int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Black);
    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setTextSize(30);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   // textPaint.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, color);
    textPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setTypeface(font);
}
```

since the text is just painted on, I am fairly confident I can't just do something like

```
Private TextSwitcher textSwitch
```

So is there an easier way to accomplish this without doing a full on custom control with animations or something?  What I'm trying to accomplish is have a progress bar that can indicate status, but the text over the progress bar needs to change between two sets of numbers at regular intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah Sure. Extend a RelativeLayout and add to it the widgets the way you like (overlapped or anything).

Comment: Can you add your answer as an answer so I can vote it up?  I'll have to check that out, didn't think about using a relative layout.   Thanks!

Comment: tick it correct :) for future users

Answer (score 0):

Extend a RelativeLayout and add to it the widgets the way you like (overlapped or anything).

```
public class MyLovelyRelativeLayoutWithCoolWidgets extends RelativeLayout {

    TextSwitcher ts;
    ProgressBar pb;

    public MyLovelyRelativeLayoutWithCoolWidgets(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //add ts and pb to this
    }

}
```